# alias not working with my mongo --eval command

Tags: bash, shell, alias, mongodb

I have the following mongo shell command to delete all users that aren't admins

```
mongo --eval 'db.users.remove({group:{$ne:"admin"}})' collection
```

This works.

I want to create an alias for this command but the following possible variations that I tried gave me the corresponding errors

1. `alias mdelna="mongo --eval 'db.users.remove({group:{$ne:"admin"}})' collection"`

   > `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`
2. `alias mdelna="mongo --eval 'db.users.remove({group:{`**`"`**`$ne`**`"`**`:"admin"}})' collection"`

   > `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`
3. `alias mdelna="mongo --eval 'db.users.remove({group:{`**`"`**`$`**`"`**`ne:"admin"}})' collection"`

   > `ReferenceError: admin is not defined`
4. `alias mdelna="mongo --eval 'db.users.remove({group:{`**`"`**`$`**`"`**`ne:`**`'`**`admin`**`'`**`}})' collection"`

   > `ReferenceError: admin is not defined`
5. `alias mdelna="mongo --eval 'db.users.remove({group:{`**`"`**`$`**`"`**`ne:``admin``}})' collection"`

   > `ReferenceError: admin is not defined`
6. `alias mdelna="mongo --eval 'var admin="admin";db.users.remove({group:{`**`"`**`$`**`"`**`ne:``admin``}})' collection"`

   **This give no error**. But it also does nothing. I check the database and it hasn't done its job.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all about escaping things so that the full command gets passed through from bash correctly.  Specifically the `$` is going to be a problem as bash will attempt to replace that with the variable `$ne` (which does not exist).  Here is the version that worked for me:

```
alias mdelna="mongo --eval 'db.users.remove({group:{\$ne:\"admin\"}})' collection"
```

I don't keep the rules for the various special characters in my head, and it's pretty tough to tease out the rules from docs, so the quick and dirty way to test this type of thing is to see what echo returns when you pass it the same argument.  Here are two for comparison:

```
$ echo "mongo --eval 'db.users.remove({group:{$ne:\"admin\"}})' collection"
mongo --eval 'db.users.remove({group:{:"admin"}})' collection
```

Note the lack of the `$ne` - it has been replaced by the empty contents of the non-existent variable by `bash`.  Now, escape the `$`, see if that fixes it:

```
$ echo "mongo --eval 'db.users.remove({group:{\$ne:\"admin\"}})' collection"
mongo --eval 'db.users.remove({group:{$ne:"admin"}})' collection
```

And now it looks much more like what we are aiming for - you can see how you could gradually build up based on the output until you get what you need.